# how to make class as singleton c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to make code separate. Below class is tokenization/detokenization class to make data as token. but when i am calling this class i have pass all the parameters, This class calling as everywhere in solution. so i want to make as static. for example

```
Tokenization.Detokenize(reader["UserPhoneNumber"].ToString(), _appSettings.TokenGroup, _appSettings.TokenTemplatePhone, _appSettings.DetokenizeServiceURL, _appSettings.BearerTokenGeneratorURL, _appSettings.App_IDPayLoad, _appSettings.App_KeyPayLoad);
```

so i just want to pass as

```
Tokenization.Detokenize(reader["UserPhoneNumber"].ToString(), _appSettings.TokenGroup, _appSettings.TokenTemplatePhone)
```

basically i want to make separate the static block and tokenizae/detokenizae  method. so it will look good. how i can do this?

```
 public  class Tokenization
{


    private static AuthToken AuthToken = null;

    private static void GetToken(string strBearTokenURL, string strAppid, string strAppkey)
    {
        RestClient tokenClinet = new RestClient(strBearTokenURL);
        tokenClinet.AddDefaultHeader("App_ID", strAppid);
        tokenClinet.AddDefaultHeader("App_Key", strAppkey);
        tokenClinet.AddDefaultHeader("apiVersion", "2");
        AuthToken = tokenClinet.Post<AuthToken>(new RestRequest()).Data;
    }

    private static bool IsTokenExpired(string strBearTokenURL, string strAppid, string strAppkey)
    {    
        if (AuthToken == null) GetToken( strBearTokenURL, strAppid, strAppkey);
        System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
        dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(AuthToken.expires_on).ToLocalTime();
        return dtDateTime <= DateTime.Now;
    }


    public static RestClient RestClientWithAuth(string strBearTokenURL, string strAppid, string strAppkey)
    {
        try
        {
            RestClient clinet = new RestClient();
            if (IsTokenExpired(strBearTokenURL, strAppid, strAppkey)) GetToken(strBearTokenURL, strAppid, strAppkey);
            clinet.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthToken.access_token);
            return clinet;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }




    public static string Tokenize(string tokenData, string tokenGroup, string tokenTemplate, string tokenizeServiceURL, string bearerTokenURL, string app_ID, string app_Key)
    {
        try
        {                    
            var request = new RestRequest(tokenizeServiceURL, Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            List<TokenProfile> payLoad = new List<TokenProfile>();               

            payLoad.Add(new TokenProfile() { tokengroup = tokenGroup, data= tokenData, tokentemplate = tokenTemplate });                

            request.AddJsonBody(payLoad);
            // execute the request
            IRestResponse<List<TokenResponse>> response = RestClientWithAuth(bearerTokenURL, app_ID, app_Key).Execute<List<TokenResponse>>(request);
            var responsestatus = response.ResponseStatus;
            return response.Data.Select(t => t.token).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }



    public static string Detokenize(string deTokenData, string tokenGroup, string tokenTemplate, string detokenizeServiceURL, string bearerTokenURL, string app_ID, string app_KeyPay)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(detokenizeServiceURL, Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            List<DeTokenProfile> payLoad = new List<DeTokenProfile>();                
            payLoad.Add(new DeTokenProfile() { tokengroup = tokenGroup, token = deTokenData, tokentemplate = tokenTemplate });
            request.AddJsonBody(payLoad);
            IRestResponse<List<DeTokenResponse>> response = RestClientWithAuth(bearerTokenURL, app_ID, app_KeyPay).Execute<List<DeTokenResponse>>(request);
            var responsestatus = response.ResponseStatus;
            return response.Data.Select(t => t.data).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: beware of singleton, it can make a hidden dependency which will cause your code to be very cumbersome to unit test, nothing wrong in making the thing a singleton but your code should not depend on the singleton without injecting it to the lib code as an interface.

Comment: Is the method always passed values from `_appSettings`? If so, just pass `_appSettings` to your method and it can grab all the values it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you would like to have some practical example of how Singleton design pattern can be implemented in practice. In your case if you want to implement, you may have to refactor your code base. Though its little costly at present but it will be good in a long run.

> **Note:** Remember The main philosophy of `Singleton design pattern` is the instance of object will be created once in a lifetime. If you would like to know
>   more about this I suggest you to [refer this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2003/february/singleton-class-private-constructor-csharp-singleton-class) and [this
>   document](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton)

```
//Interface declaration
    public interface ITokennization
    {
        object TokenizationClassMethod();
    }

    //Interface Inheritance/Implementation in class 
    public class TokenizationClass : ITokennization
    {

        private static TokenizationClass _singletonInstance;

        private static readonly object padlock = new object();

        //Default constructor
        public TokenizationClass()
        {

        }
        // SingleTon Design Pattern 
        public static TokenizationClass CheckSingleInstance()
        {
            if (_singletonInstance == null)
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    //Checks instance each time 
                    if (_singletonInstance == null)
                        //creates  new instance if no instances already created
                        _singletonInstance = new TokenizationClass();
                }
            }

            return _singletonInstance;
        }
        // Class Method
        public object TokenizationClassMethod()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Hope this would help

Answer (score -1):

You should try this 
(Important: I don't try this code)

```
public class Tokenization
{
    private static Tokenization Instance = new Tokenization();
    private AuthToken AuthToken = null;

    private Tokenization(){}

    private void GetToken(string strBearTokenURL, string strAppid, string strAppkey)
    {
        RestClient tokenClinet = new RestClient(strBearTokenURL);
        tokenClinet.AddDefaultHeader("App_ID", strAppid);
        tokenClinet.AddDefaultHeader("App_Key", strAppkey);
        tokenClinet.AddDefaultHeader("apiVersion", "2");
        AuthToken = tokenClinet.Post<AuthToken>(new RestRequest()).Data;
    }

    private bool IsTokenExpired(string strBearTokenURL, string strAppid, string strAppkey)
    {    
        if (AuthToken == null) GetToken( strBearTokenURL, strAppid, strAppkey);
        System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
        dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(AuthToken.expires_on).ToLocalTime();
        return dtDateTime <= DateTime.Now;
    }


    public RestClient RestClientWithAuth(string strBearTokenURL, string strAppid, string strAppkey)
    {
        try
        {
            RestClient clinet = new RestClient();
            if (IsTokenExpired(strBearTokenURL, strAppid, strAppkey)) GetToken(strBearTokenURL, strAppid, strAppkey);
            clinet.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthToken.access_token);
            return clinet;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }




    public string Tokenize(string tokenData, string tokenGroup, string tokenTemplate, string tokenizeServiceURL, string bearerTokenURL, string app_ID, string app_Key)
    {
        try
        {                    
            var request = new RestRequest(tokenizeServiceURL, Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            List<TokenProfile> payLoad = new List<TokenProfile>();               

            payLoad.Add(new TokenProfile() { tokengroup = tokenGroup, data= tokenData, tokentemplate = tokenTemplate });                

            request.AddJsonBody(payLoad);
            // execute the request
            IRestResponse<List<TokenResponse>> response = RestClientWithAuth(bearerTokenURL, app_ID, app_Key).Execute<List<TokenResponse>>(request);
            var responsestatus = response.ResponseStatus;
            return response.Data.Select(t => t.token).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }


    public string Detokenize(string deTokenData, string tokenGroup, string tokenTemplate, string detokenizeServiceURL, string bearerTokenURL, string app_ID, string app_KeyPay)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(detokenizeServiceURL, Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            List<DeTokenProfile> payLoad = new List<DeTokenProfile>();                
            payLoad.Add(new DeTokenProfile() { tokengroup = tokenGroup, token = deTokenData, tokentemplate = tokenTemplate });
            request.AddJsonBody(payLoad);
            IRestResponse<List<DeTokenResponse>> response = RestClientWithAuth(bearerTokenURL, app_ID, app_KeyPay).Execute<List<DeTokenResponse>>(request);
            var responsestatus = response.ResponseStatus;
            return response.Data.Select(t => t.data).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Use method:

`Tokenization.Instance.Detokenize()` same like

Comment: Could you explain what changes you have made to the code and why? Very difficult to figure it out otherwise.

Comment: I would go to https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton to check how to implemented singleton in thread safe manner

Comment: I don't change the code body but I add a private constructor. I make singleton this class.
External access use this : private static Tokenization Instance = new Tokenization();
External classes don't instance this class because of:  private Tokenization(){}